# i/o pins 0 1 2 3V GND ble transmitter and receiver that can connect to the raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3

I'm doing a project where I have the BBC's microbit and a Raspberry Pi 3, where the microbit acts like a sensor and the pi is like a server, the only trouble is the microbit cannot wirelessly connect to the raspberry pi using micropython, so is there a BLE 0 1 2 3V GND I/O pins transmitter and receiver that can wirelessly connect to the raspberry pi?

Answer (score 3):

The ring connectors on the micro:bit are designed to accept [4mm banana plugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_connector#/media/File:4mm-plugs.png), and provide:

- 0, 1, 2: Digital/analogue input/output
- 3V: +3V
- GND: Ground

There are no common devices available which you will be able to connect to those pins to provide wireless communication between your micro:bit and a Raspberry Pi.

The micro:bit does include a Bluetooth interface. The best example I could find of using Bluetooth to communicate between a micro:bit and a Raspberry Pi is [this Youtube video from user Barry Byford](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4wTXVmsWmE). In the comments below the video he includes a set of links to the resources needed to get everything working.

In essence he:

- [Installed BlueZ 5.40](https://github.com/ukBaz/python-bluezero/blob/master/docs/install_bluez.rst) (at the time of writing an experimental version)
- Paired the Pi and the micro:bit using bluetoothctl (second explanatory video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxPsVozglnM&feature=youtu.be)
- Ran a Python script (currently hosted on his Github page [here](https://github.com/ukBaz/python-bluezero/blob/master/examples/microbit_button.py)) on the Pi which used the BlueZ dbus API to receive data from the micro:bit over Bluetooth.